# WPF unresponsive UI issues

Tags: .net, wpf, multithreading, user-interface

I have an application that is displaying some oddball behaviour and I can't figure it out.  Basically my app starts up, and attempts to connect to some external hardware that is connected via USB.  While this goes on I display a 'busy' window that has some simple animations.  Intermittently however, the UI will completely hang (animation and all) while the hardware initializes.

The thing is, the problem is intermittent, and I have already ensured that it is running on a background thread (via Task.StartNew). I have tried replacing the hardware initialization calls with things like 'Thread.Sleep(5000)' to simulate a hang, and the UI behaves correctly so I am kind of out of ideas here.

Is it possible that the hardware itself (and unmanaged library that I use to interact with it) is somehow interfering with the system and causing the issue?  I'd really hate to resort to blaming hardware, but is there some other avenue of investigation or other possible software problem that I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

Do you connect to the device using a COM library?  If COM is brought in as STA, it can end up delegating some of its work to the UI thread, causing a blocking call on a different thread to sometimes block the main UI thread as well.  Very annoying, I know.  Well-behaved COM components won't do this, but I've run into it before.  You can diagnose if this is happening by isolating only the call that causes the blocking in a test application, with nothing else occurring.  Create a UI timer and record ticks.  If the ticks stop firing when you call the COM method on a separate thread, the COM component is behaving badly.

Comment: OK, I'll take a shot at that and see what is going on.  From what I can tell, the library is COM with a thin managed wrapper.  Let it be said that the manufacturer is well known for hardware, and not software.

Answer (score 1):

I would check if changing process affinity makes a difference. It could be that the usb driver is sloppy, and does something timeconsuming in the hardware interrupt. This could block whatever thread was running on the core that services the interrupt.

There could be other explanations, but if the problem is related to a specific core, it suggests that the driver is the problem.

Please note that my knowledge of windows driver models is quit outdated, so it may no longeer work this way.

Comment: yes, the hardware in question isn't known to have the greatest software components.  I'll take a look into your suggestion.